# Why is service null in this call?

Tags: java, jsf

I have this method on a bean:

```
public boolean isLinkInDescriptionForCheckbox(final Service service) {
    logger.info("Testing if there is a link for {}", service);
    return Service.UK_ADDRESS_CORRECTION == service;
}
```

...and this in my JSP:

```
<c:if test="#{serviceUiDescriptions.isLinkInDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}">
```

My log tells me this:

```
c.n.c.s.c.ServiceUiDescriptions - Testing if there is a link for null
```

And YET this works fine:

```
<label for="checkbox_#{service.name()}"> #{serviceUiDescriptions.getDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}</label>
```

...which is the line just before the `c:if` tag

So: In the line just before, service is not null, but in the test for the `c:if` line service is null.

Here's the whole fragment

```
<ui:repeat var="service" value="#{servicesBean.getAvailableServicesOfGroup(servicePresentationGroup)}">
    <div class="servicePresentation" title="#{serviceUiDescriptions.getLongDescription(service)}">
        <span class="checkboxSpan"> 
            <input type="checkbox” name="checkbox_#{service.name()}" value="true" checked="checked"
                                    id="checkbox_#{service.name()}" />
        </span>
            <h2>
                <label for="checkbox_#{service.name()}"> #{serviceUiDescriptions.getDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}</label>
                <c:if test="#{serviceUiDescriptions.isLinkInDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}">
                    <span class="smallText">
                        <h:outputLink value="#{serviceUiDescriptions.getLinkInDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}" >
                        #{serviceUiDescriptions.getLinkDescriptionInDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}
                        </h:outputLink>
                    </span>
                </c:if>
            </h2>
        </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

This is what I get - look no link:

[image: look no link]

Comment: Where is service defined in your JSP?

Comment: Added the whole fragment

Comment: Is `servicesBean.getAvailableServicesOfGroup(servicePresentationGroup)` null?  JSP's expression language is ["null friendly"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446632/el-and-cout-prints-empty-string-for-null-attributes-but-throws-exception-when) so `service.name()` will not raise an exception even if `service` is null, but as soon as you pass something back into Java land, you need to be careful about dereferencing null.

Comment: for my dollar, this looks like JSF.  If it is JSF, consider immediate evaluation for the test condition ('test="${blah') instead of delayed (not sure that is the correct term) 'test="#{blah'.

Comment: @DwB Sorry, changing to $ does not work any better

Comment: @MikeSamuel the available services is not null. serviceUiDescriptions.getLongDescription(service) does not get a null a little higher up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements may be one line after another but they are not executed at the same time. `<c:if>` is a JSTL-Tag which is executed during view build time. The other expression will be wrapped in a `<h:outputText>` which will be executed during view render time. And I guess the service will be created in between.

To solve your problem you could replace the `<c:if>` with

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{serviceUiDescriptions.isLinkInDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}">
```

or replace the `<span>` element with

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="smallText" rendered="#{serviceUiDescriptions.isLinkInDescriptionForCheckbox(service)}">
```

(without the `<c:if>`).

See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984)
- [JavaServer Faces (JSF) - ui:repeat not showing new elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611767)

Comment: Tested. Works. Thanks!